# QT in Visual Studio 2019, new added class that inherit from QObject not linked properly

Tags: c++, qt, moc

I am using **VS 2019** for developing QT using the QT extension, however, when I add a class to the project that inherits from QObject and added Q_OBJECT, I am getting linker errors such as :

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl MyThread::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?
```

It does seem like the new class is not build or compiled properly, something related to MOC,
How to resolve this and include the file I just added to be MOCe build?

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: did you include QObject? `#include <QObject>`

Comment: Try to rerun the `qmake` utility. I.e., fully rebuild your project.